# Why does ZSH finish executing a function after exit was called from a trap?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh, signals

Consider the following script:

```
trap "echo TRAPPEDTERM >&2; exit" TERM

termself () {
    kill -TERM $$
    echo "Survived TERM!"
}
termself
echo "Bye."
```

Executed using BASH, this simply prints `TRAPPEDTERM`.  On ZSH, the `termself` function completes, printing `Survived TERM!`, but does not return to `echo "Bye."`  So why, and how can I get BASH's behavior under ZSH? I'm currently using `eval $functions[termself]`, which is not natural.

```
$ bash -x ./termself.sh 
+ trap 'echo TRAPPEDTERM >&2; exit' TERM
+ termself
+ kill -TERM 293517
++ echo TRAPPEDTERM
TRAPPEDTERM
++ exit
```

---

```
$ zsh --no-rcs -x ./termself.sh 
+./termself.sh:3> trap 'echo TRAPPEDTERM >&2; exit' TERM
+./termself.sh:9> termself
+termself:1> kill -TERM 293525
+termself:1> echo TRAPPEDTERM
TRAPPEDTERM
+termself:1> exit
+termself:2> echo 'Survived TERM!'
Survived TERM!
```

---

```
$ bash --version ; zsh --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it sounds like a bug to me. It seems you can work around it with `exec exit 1` instead of `exit 1`.

Comment: Merci @StéphaneChazelas, I'll wait a couple days and report this to the mailing list if no one can come up with an explanation.  I tested that on ZSH 5.5.1 with the same result.

Comment: See also `zsh -c 'trap "exit 1; echo still here" EXIT; f() { exit; echo f; }; f'` which outputs `still here`. I think you can already at lease raise the question on the zsh-workers ml.

Comment: Using `TRAPTERM() { return 1; }` instead of `trap 'exit 1' TERM` also seems to work around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in zsh which [was already reported back in 2019](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2019/msg00045.html) and referenced in [the list of known bugs (`Etc/BUGS` in the source distribution)](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/04f41c6b6e3a9c688701cb130ff68f99306beb52/tree/Etc/BUGS).

A related bug (whereby `zsh -c 'trap "exit 1; echo x" EXIT; f() { exit; echo f; }; f'` would output `x` as mentioned in comments) was [fixed when reported in 2021](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2021/msg00452.html), but that one remains.